# Natbib prints the reference identifier in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style, apacite

I use

```
\usepackage[sort,comma,authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{xxx}
```

When LaTeX produces my bibliography it also outputs the reference identifier..

This is what I have in my `.bib` file.

[image]

And this is what is printed in my PDF.

[image]

Why is the reference identifier printed in the PDF?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! For future questions, it's helpful to add a compilable sample document rather than code fragments, and instead of posting images of your `.bib` file, posting the actual `.bib` entry also as code.  You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apacite` package must be loaded to use the `apacite` bibliography style. You can use `natbib` citation commands by adding the `natbibapa` package option, but remove your `\usepackage[...]{natbib}` line from the preamble when you do.

So you need:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```